# How to get an angle from 3 points?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I have three 2D points $A, B, C$. $C$ is the centre, $A$ is initial point, $B$ is secondary point (less important, or gathered after $A$). How to get an angle formed by $A, B, C$ where distance between $A$ and $C$ is used as circle radius?

[image: A,B,C,angle]

Comment: Note that there are two angles, one clockwise and on counter-clockwise. Is it safe to assume that you only want a semicircle? Or do you want to be able to "sweep out" a full circle?

Comment: What do you mean "get an angle"?  You can write the equation for a circle centered at $C$ with radius $AC$ and the line $AB$, then solve them as two simultaneous equations to find your "used" point, if that is what you are trying to construct, then use the law of cosines to find the angle.  Please think clearly about what you are looking for and describe it more carefully.

Comment: The angle is $180° - 2\angle CAB$. This is easy to see, if you draw line $AB$ horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to follow.

1) line $AB$, be $\cal L$

2) circle $\cal C$ of center $C$ and radius $\overline{AC}=r$

3) intersection $\cal L\cap\cal C$ gives points $A$ and $C'$

4) $\overline{AC'}=d=\overline{AB}-\overline{C'B}=2r\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$

5) the angle $\theta$ is the solution.

►The geometrical construction is immediate.

►Analytically you have, $A=(a_1,a_2)$, $B=(b_1,b_2)$, $C=(0,0)$, $\overline{AC}=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}=r$, $\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(b_1-a_1)^2+(b_2-a_2)^2}$. Then

$\cal L:\frac{y-a_2}{x-a_1}=\frac{b_2-a_2}{b_1-a_1}$

$\cal C: x^2+y^2=r^2$

Solve the system $$\begin{cases}y=\frac{b_2-a_2}{b_1-a_1}(x-a_1)+a_2\\y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\end{cases}$$ which gives the points $A$ and $C'=(c'_1,c'_2)$.

$ \overline{AC'}=d=\sqrt{(b_1-a_1)^2+(b_2-a_2)^2}-\sqrt{(c'_1-b_1)^2+(c'_2-b_2)^2}$.

You finish with $$\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{d}{2r}$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer!) Could you please also provide analytical solution for $y$?

Comment: You are welcome. Put, for short, $m=\frac{b_2-a_2}{b_1-a_1}$ and $A=-a_1m+a_2$ so you have $$y=mx+A=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\Rightarrow (m^2+1)x^2+2mAx+(A^2-r^2)$$    You get $$x=\frac{-mA\pm\sqrt{(m^2+1)r^2-A^2}}{m^2+1}$$ thus $$y=\large?$$

Comment: @DuckQueen: Attention to the edition putting correctly $\overline{C'B}$ in wich I have put by distraction $\overline{C'A}$ instead of $\overline{C'B}$ (immediately before of "You finish with").